# Quickfix: Como usar SSL con python

Tags: python, ssl

Tengo problemas para conectar mi cliente **`QuickFIX`** desarrollado en Python. El archivo de configuración no responde como me gustaría.

Si cambio la ruta (una ruta incorrecta, para forzar el error) al archivo **`*.pem`** y reinicie la aplicación. La aplicación no hace nada, simplemente se ejecuta normalmente.

Es como si no se leyera la configuración.

En este tutorial ([FIX Protocol en python](https://medium.com/@federico_dv/fix-protocol-en-python-primeros-pasos-e-implementaci%C3%B3n-29a130b71ffc)) se menciona: la implementación en Python de quickfix no es compatible con SSL, ¿es cierto?

Esto es para una implementación de Python en Windows con [QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/)

```
[DEFAULT]
PersistMessages=Y
ConnectionType=initiator
UseDataDictionary=Y 
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:00
FileStorePath=incoming 
FileLogPath=outgoing   


[SESSION]
SSLEnable=Y
SSLProtocol=TLSv1
ClientCertificateFil=C:\python\pyarb\cert\cert.pem
ClientCertificateKeyFile=C:\python\pyarb\cert\key.pem
StartTime=14:00:00
SenderCompID=AGENT
TargetCompID=FIX
EndTime=00:00:00
ConnectionType=initiator 
ApplVerID=9
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=9
TransportDataDictionary=quickfix_dicts\FIX50SP1.xml
AppDataDictionary=quickfix_dicts\FIX50SP1.xml
DataDictionary=quickfix_dicts\FIX50SP1.xml
SocketConnectPort=xxxx
SocketConnectHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=N
ResetSeqNumFlag=N
```

Comment: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.0.0/usage/secure_communications.html pudes ver esto para que te guies mejor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es que la librería de Quickfix para python al día de la fecha no soporta conexiones SSL/TLS por lo que la solucion que me recomendaron fue usar Stunnel.
Desgraciadamente eso no sirvió para mi porque no pude hacerlo funcinoar asique tuve que hacer mi propio Stunnel el cual está en este link
[Como hacer un Proxy Socket Python no bloqueante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266314/como-hacer-un-proxy-socket-python-no-bloqueante/266865#266865)

espero que le sea de utilidad para alguien