# Como hacer un Proxy Socket Python no bloqueante

Tags: python, hilos, socket, proxy

[image: Diagrama de conexion]

Tengo el siguiente esquema que figura en la imagen, tengo un cliente que debe pasar por este "proxy" ya que el desarrollo del cliente no soporta conexion TLS/SSL para los sockets. esto funciona bien.

El problema es que funciona 1 response para 1 request

El cliente envia un request recibe un response, automaticamente este "proxy" se bloquea esperando otro request.

Yo necesito que se quede escuchando posibles responses sin que antes exista un request de parte del cliente.

No se si sea necesario el uso de Threads o Si con el No-blocking sera suficiente

```py
import socket
import ssl

host_servidor   = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
port_servidor   = 5555

host_local  = '127.0.0.1' 
port_local  = 4444



with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:

    sock.bind((host_local,port_local))
    sock.listen(2)

    print('[*] Socket abierto en {} {}'.format(host_local, port_local))

    conn,addr = sock.accept()
    with conn:
        print("[*] Conexion establecida")
        while True:
            request = conn.recv(1024)
            if not request:
                print('[*] Cerrando conexion con cliente ')
                break
            else:
                print('[*] Datos recibidos desde cliente: {}'.format(request.decode()))
                if(not sock_servidor):
                    context = ssl.create_default_context()
                    ssock = socket.create_connection((host_servidor, port_servidor))
                    sock_servidor = context.wrap_socket(ssock, server_hostname=host_servidor)
                    print(sock_servidor.version())

                sock_servidor.sendall(request)
                response = sock_servidor.recv(1024)
                if not response:
                    break
                print('[*] Datos recibidos desde servidor:',response.decode())

                if not response:
                    print('[-] No se recibio informacion de servidor:')
                    sock_servidor.close()
                    break
                else:               

                    conn.send(response)
```

Comment: Ya que tienes dos sockets de los que puedes recibir datos, si intentas hacer un `recv()` en uno de ellos se te bloqueará hasta recibir datos por él, impidiéndote entonces "enterarte" de cuándo llegan datos por el otro. La solución para esto es usar un multiplexor de E/S como select(), o su interfaz de más alto nivel [selectors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html#module-selectors), que te permite por así decir "esperar datos en varios sockets a la vez".

Comment: Si, gracias fue lo que hice. usar select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno despues de investigar y darme la cabeza contra la pared varias veces,
La solución "mas simple" que encontré para mi caso en particular fué la siguiente: Calculo que se puede mejorar aun más añadiendo bloques try except, y de otras maneras como hacer uso correcto de la variable escritura la cual no supe darle buen uso

Espero sea de ayuda para alguien ya que me parece algo sumamente util.

Si todavia no se entiende lo que hace es básicamente un Stunnel solo que sin posibilidad de configurarle arhivos key usando un contexto por defecto que trae la libreria ssl de python.

```py
import socket
import ssl
import select

host_servidor   = "xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx"
port_servidor   = 4431

host_local  = '127.0.0.1' 
port_local  = 4444

sock_servidor = False
conn = False
sock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.bind((host_local,port_local))
    sock.listen(2)
    sock.setblocking(0)
    print('[*] Socket abierto en {} {}'.format(host_local, port_local))


except Exception as e:
    print(e)

lista_sockets = [sock]
salidas = []
mensajes_to_byma = []
mensajes_to_algoritmo = []
falg = True
while falg:
    lectura, escritura, errores = select.select(lista_sockets,lista_sockets,lista_sockets)

    for l in lectura:

        if l is sock:
            print("[*] Algoritmo conectado")
            conn,addr = sock.accept()
            lista_sockets.append(conn)
            conn.settimeout(0.0)
            context = ssl.create_default_context()
            ssock = socket.create_connection((host_servidor, port_servidor))
            sock_servidor = context.wrap_socket(ssock, server_hostname=host_servidor)
            sock_servidor.setblocking(0)
            lista_sockets.append(sock_servidor)
            print("[*] conexion establecida con Servidor remoto")
            print(sock_servidor.version())


        elif l is sock_servidor:
            response = l.recv(1024)
            if not response:
                print("[-] Desconectando por servidor Remoto")
                falg = False
                break
            else:
                print("[*] Recibiendo datos de servidor Remoto")
                print(response.decode())
                mensajes_to_algoritmo.append(response)

        elif l is conn:
            print("[*] mensajes_to_byma desde Algoritmo")
            request = l.recv(1024)
            if not request:
                print("[-] data vacia")
                falg = False
                break
            else:
                print("[*] Recibiendo data en lectura")
                print(request.decode())
                mensajes_to_byma.append(request)
        else:
            print("[*] Other request")      

        if mensajes_to_byma:
            print("[*] Enviando datos a Servidor remoto")
            for m in mensajes_to_byma:
                print(m)
                sock_servidor.sendall(m)
            mensajes_to_byma = []

        if mensajes_to_algoritmo:
            print("[*] Enviando datos al ALGORITMO")

            for m in mensajes_to_algoritmo:
                print(m)
                conn.sendall(m)
            mensajes_to_algoritmo = []


    for e in escritura:
        pass
    for e in errores:
        print(e)
        break
sock_servidor.close()
sock.close()
```